# How to optimise a Motorola Wing 5.3 Access Point for UDP traffic

Tags: wireless-networking, udp

I have a motorola wing v 5.3 which I need to optmise for UDP traffic.
I have some UDP packet loss and I think that if I change the AP configuration I would get a better result.

Anyone has experience with this AP or even comments about UDP over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Config, Wireless, WLAN QoS policy, then select the policy and select "multimedia optimization" and give the mulitcast MAC address so that AP will transfer the UDP packet to unicast packet.